Consulta compleja de consulta xquery con salida xml
Estoy tratando de realizar la siguiente consulta xquery, paso archivo xml.

se me pide lo siguiente...

NO tengo ni idea de como, empezar a atajarlo
Si me pudiesen ayudar a entenderlo les estaré agradecido

El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato. Además, explica el problema específico que estás teniendo.

Si no tienes ni idea de como empezar me parece que podrías empezar a leer una introducción a XPath y XQuery, como por ejemplo https://www.altova.com/es/mobiletogether/xpath-intro.
